# SQL pivoting data from DNN user data

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am trying to export data from a DNN database to a new system, so I was trying to pivot the DNN data into a more logical form first... but I can't get my code to work.

Can anyone see what is wrong?

The error I am getting suggests the 2 fields in the 1st row are invalid column names?

```
SELECT [Rownumber], [columnheading]

FROM
(
  SELECT

     udd1.UserDefinedRowId as Rownumber, 
     udf1.FieldTitle as columnheading,
     convert(nvarchar(max),udd1.FieldValue) as newFieldValue 
  FROM UserDefinedData udd1

  INNER JOIN UserDefinedFields udf1
    ON udf1.UserDefinedFieldId = udd1.UserDefinedFieldId

  INNER JOIN UserDefinedRows udr1 
    ON udr1.UserDefinedRowId = udd1.UserDefinedRowId
    WHERE udr1.ModuleId = 3806

) AS UserData

PIVOT

(
  MAX(Rownumber)

  FOR columnheading IN  ( "Evidence", "Contact", "Action Required")

) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: When you use pivot then you're changing the value of a field into columns. So selecting the same fields you're using for the pivot won't work. But you can use a `select * ` in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

I think your pivot output you are looking is for newfieldvalue so it has to go in max column and select has to be the columns listing as below:

```
SELECT [Rownumber], [Evidence], [Contact], [Action Required]
FROM
(
  SELECT

     udd1.UserDefinedRowId as Rownumber, 
     udf1.FieldTitle as columnheading,
     convert(nvarchar(max),udd1.FieldValue) as newFieldValue 
  FROM UserDefinedData udd1

  INNER JOIN UserDefinedFields udf1
    ON udf1.UserDefinedFieldId = udd1.UserDefinedFieldId

  INNER JOIN UserDefinedRows udr1 
    ON udr1.UserDefinedRowId = udd1.UserDefinedRowId
    WHERE udr1.ModuleId = 3806

) AS UserData
PIVOT
(
  MAX(newFieldValue)
  FOR columnheading IN  ( [Evidence], [Contact], [Action Required])
) AS PivotTable;
```